# value of $m$ and $c$ in Circles

Tags: geometry

If line $y=mx+c$ is a common tangents to the given circles and $r_{4}=r_{1}+r_{2}$ and $r_{5}=r_{2}+r_{3}$

where $r_{i}$ is the radius of circle $C_{i}$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$

Then value of $m+c$ is

[image]

what i try

$\displaystyle r_{1}=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$ and $\displaystyle r_{2}=\frac{2m+c-2}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$

and $\displaystyle r_{3}=\frac{6m-7+c}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$ and $\displaystyle r_{4}=\frac{m+2+c}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$ and $\displaystyle r_{5}=\frac{4m+6+c}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$

substituting these value in $\displaystyle r_{4}=r_{1}+r_{2}$ and $\displaystyle r_{5}=r_{2}+r_{3}$ and solving for $m,c$

Is there is any smart way to solve it Help me please

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! Substituting in $r_1+r_2 = r_4$ and $r_2+r_3=r_5$, we get the two equations
$$
\frac{c}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} + \frac{2m+c-2}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} = \frac{m+2+c}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}\\
\frac{2m+c-2}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} + \frac{6m-7+c}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} = \frac{4m+6+c}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
$$
This might look messy, but *all* those fractions have the same denominator. So the denominators can just be cleared away, and we're left with
$$
c + 2m+c-2 = m+2+c\\
2m+c-2+ 6m-7+c = 4m+6+c
$$
which isn't too hard to solve.